# A problem when I try to evaluate the integral

Tags: calculus

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Wbu.jpg)

I want to evaluate the equation at the first line,and I use two method ,the first one I  directly integrate the equation,and the second one I change the equation from Cartesian coordinate to polar coordinate,and integrate it,but eventually I got two different result,I don't know why,hope someone can tell me the reason,thank.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type your questions instead of posting images whenever feasible, as here.  Images can't be browsed, and links can break.

Comment: $a^4/2$ is correct.

Comment: @saulspatz sorry, I will do it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (1) note that $x$ can be negative. But when $x<0$ it is no longer true that $(x^2)^{3/2} = x^3$.

Comment: I see ,thank you.